# How to unit test a project outside visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have made a project in visual studio and also implemented unit testing.
The code working fine with the unit testing.

Now I have a doubt that is it possible to implement unit testing outside the visual studio environment such that I only use the exe generated by my project and test it for multiple cases?

I am looking for an option which can utilise my current unit testing implementation

I am new to unit testing, so any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing MSTest without Visual Studio is not quite trivial thing. [This tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334) was very useful to me in this regard.
Originated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884056/456181)

Comment: I added a "shortcut", since the answer you linked to only provided another link

Answer (score 1):

You can use outside library like NUnit, there is manager to run your test

Comment: Nunit is an option but I have already implemented unit testing provided by .net, So I was actually looking for an option in which i could use my current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If from outside, you mean outside of Visual Studio IDE, then you can use [mstest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which VS internally uses. This is stand alone in sense, that host doesn't need VS installed. Thus e.g. a build system can call this and do unit test towards the end of build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Microsoft test framework, you can run [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your test classes as per this SO answer then you can run them in either MSTest or NUnit, based on a compilation option. Hope this helps!

[Using both MSTest and NUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053557/using-both-mstest-and-nunit)